# Init a select in dart and polymer via an http call

Tags: dart, polymer

Is there a procedure to call an "init" method on a polymer element in Dart in order to populate it?
I have a polymer template (still not sure it's correct) and I want to populate it with the results of an HttpRequest.  I can populate with a static list, but not sure how to populate it with a dynamic list made via an http call.

Are there examples anywhere?

I'm still trying to come up to speed on Dart and Polymer ...
My hacks are at https://gist.github.com/fils/6270699

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting the init code inside a `created()` lifecycle method? You can see an example of that at https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/blob/polymer/example/todomvc/web/todo_row.dart